# Formula for X "successes" with X 10 sided die.

Tags: probability, dice

I am trying to create a formula for the % chance of having Y number of dice hit a number 8, 9 or 10 out of X possible. For example the chance of having 7 dice out of 10 dice be one of the 3 numbers.

In other words I need a formula where you can insert X(number of 10 sided dice rolled) and Y(minimum number of die you want to hit 8, 9 or 10 (In other words 3/10)), and get the percent chance of this happening.

I've spent all night coming up with different formulae that describe the problem but none of them have worked... Please help.

Cheers.

P.S. The full extent of the problem is that whenever one of the dice hits 10, another die is added to the value X but I imagine that would make the formula extremely complicated but if you have a reasonable way to add it to the equation then please go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you have $x$ number of dice (of specific shape&probability) and you define a specific result to be a "success" or a "failure" (in your example, rolling an 8,9, or 10 on a d10).  You roll *all* $x$ dice and count how many successes you had total, and you are interested in the probability of having either *exactly* or *at least* $y$ successes.

This is given by the [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  It says that having *exactly* $r$ successes out of $n$ trials with a specific probability $p$ for success in each trial occurs with probability $$P(X=r)=\binom{n}{r}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$$

If you are interested instead in *at least* $r$ successes instead, then add up each case of exactly more to get $$P(X\geq r) = \sum\limits_{i=r}^n \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

---

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20i%3D5%20to%2013%20of%20%28%2813%20choose%20i%29%20.3%5Ei%20.7%5E%2813-i%29%29)'s calculations for your specific choice of numbers below.

---

Your calculator said "not solvable"?  That suggests to me that you probably used an incorrect syntax somewhere.  If using a graphing calculator in the Ti-83 family, to calculate the probability of **exactly** $r$ successes out of $n$ trials with probability of success $p$, you would type

> binompdf(n,p,r)

To calculate probability of **at most** $r$ successes out of $n$ trials with probability of success $p$, you would type

> binomcdf(n,p,r)

To calculate probability of **at least** $r$ successes out of $n$ trials with probability of success $p$, you would type

> 1 - binomcdf(n,p,r-1)

To do so without built in commands, then for the case of **at least** $r$ successes out of ... you would type something like this:

> sum(seq((N nCr I)*(P)^I * (1-P)^(N-I),I,R,N,1))

The specific syntax for summation is:

> sum(seq(  description of sequence here, what value is used for index, starting value of index, ending value of index, index step-size))

To find more information on how to use specific functions of your graphing calculator, I recommend reading the manual which should either have come with it at time of purchase, or is available online on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to use these but to no avail - I do think that has more to do with it having been too long since I last did this level of math. But the formula does seem familiar.
I attempted to solve it for the following value: r=5 (number of successes required), n=13 (number of dice) and p=0.3 (probability for a D10 roll one of the 3 values). And for starters my graph calculator said it was not solvable (which seems odd to me and makes me think I must have misunderstood something). When I solved the first equation by hand I got P=0.00036422012718 which I know to be wrong...

Comment: @LordVictor according to wolfram alpha, it comes out to be $\approx .345$ for at least 5, or $\approx .18$ for exactly 5 successes, link added above (its not displaying correctly in comments)